# Raspberry Pi Zero Headless Setup ssh access over usb cable

Tags: ssh, usb, putty, raspberry-pi

I am currently trying to set up my brand new raspberry pi zero using just a usb cable, an sd card, and a computer. I followed [this tutorial](https://desertbot.io/blog/headless-pi-zero-ssh-access-over-usb-windows) when trying to connect to the raspberry pi.
I downloaded the latest [Raspbian image: Raspbian stretch with desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and etched it onto an sd card,
then did everything the tutorial asked up to step 9, which I could not complete.
some of the things I did are below:

Append `dtoverlay=dwc2` into the config.txt file.

Add `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` to the cmdline.txt file in the specified location

Created an empty file titled ssh. I also installed bonjour and PuTTY, however when I try to connect to the pi via ssh on putty by typing in `raspberrypi.local` in the Host Name(or IP address) text field and opening the connection, the following message comes up:

"Unable to open connection to raspberrypi.local Host does not exist"

[image of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXs66.png)

This is my first time using a raspberry pi, can someone please tell me why this is happening, and how I should fix it so I can connect to the pi and set it up?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem - I found that Windows misidentified my Pi Zero as a COM device - as [this article](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget) said it might. So check your device manager for a 'USB Ethernet/RNDIS Gadget' - or something similar. If it's not present, here's what I had to do;

Go to [this Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Acer%20Incorporated.%20-%20Other%20hardware%20-%20USB%20Ethernet/RNDIS%20Gadget), and download 'Acer Incorporated  Other hardware - USB Ethernet/RNDIS Gadget' driver (make sure to pick the Windows 7, 8 or later version).

Use Windows Explorer or 7-zip or something similar to open the downloaded file and extract the contents into a folder.

Find your Pi as a COM device in Device Manager - then right-click, select Properties, Driver, Update Driver, Select from installed drivers, let me pick from a list, have disk.

In the file dialog, pick the folder you extracted to earlier, and install the driver. Then disconnect & reconnect your Pi, and it should show up as an ethernet device now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try to connect to `pi@raspberrypi.local` as host name using PuTTY instead of `raspberrypi.local` (it solved the problem for me).